# Is there any way to access USB drive from desktop

Tags: usb

My Ubuntu is 12.10 is running on HP 4000 PC, it has several usb ports, I just attached a flush drive to one of the USB ports. How can I access my USB flash drive? Thanks for your comments.

Kevin

Answer (score 1):

[image: How to access "Computer"]
It should be available from the Unity launcher, if not try clicking on the desktop > go > computer. This will bring up all the drives connected to the computer.

If you would like a shortcut to access "computer" you can install "tweak tool" from the Software centre which gives you this option.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can I start Unity launcher from 12.10? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The launcher will already be running (default), it's the bar at the side with all the application launchers on, You may have to "push" your mouse against the left edge of your screen.

Answer (score 0):

[ClassicMenu Indicator](http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/classicmenu-indicator/) also can help you.To install it open your terminal and type as

```
wget http://www.florian-diesch.de/software/classicmenu-indicator/dist/classicmenu-indicator_0.07_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i classicmenu-indicator_0.07_all.deb
```

Then It will appear in your Unity Top panel.

For more Information click on the Link of Classic Menu Indicator.